# how to set same value to multiple variable in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have to set a same value for two variables in TCL.How I can set ?? Now am using below command to set ? Please provide me an alternative solution.

```
set Server 192.168.0.1

set srvipaddr  192.168.0.1
```

The Word "Server" will be displayed in GUI.If we enter an ip address in Server field it has to set same value in Server and srvipaddr(variable name used in functions) in that configuration file.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to do this

**The one liner:**

The result of `set` is the value being set, so that can be used as the value for another `set` command:

```
set Server [set srvipaddr 192.168.0.1]
```

**Using a variable as the value**

You can also set the first variable, then use it to define the second variable:

```
set Server 192.168.0.1
set srvipaddr $Server
```

**Using a loop**

Because "everything's a string" in tcl -- including variable names -- you can iterate over a list of variable names:

```
foreach var {Server srvipaddr} {
    set $var 192.168.0.1
}
```

**Variable aliases**

There is an advanced technique that lets you have two names point to the same variable. This command is [upvar](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/upvar.htm), and works like this:

```
set Server 192.168.0.1
upvar 0 Server srvipaddr
```

When you do the above, both point to the same memory location, so if you change one you also change the other. This is a somewhat unusual way to use upvar; it's usually a way to implement "call by name" semantics.

Comment: Hi Bryan Oakley,All the above commands working well. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the following is what you are looking at?

```
set Server 192.168.0.1
set srvipaddr $Server
```

Answer (score 1):

The `set` command returns it's value, so you can write

```
set Server [set srvipaddr 192.168.0.1]
```

But that becomes less readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many variables to set to the same value, you can use a loop and use the variable names in a list, for example:

```
% set variables [list one two three]
% foreach n $variables {
      set $n 1
  }

% puts $one
1
% puts $two
1
% puts $three
1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set Server 192.168.0.1
upvar 0 Server srvipaddr
```

One variable, two names.

Comment: The advantage of this technique is that it keeps the values synchronized.